# Degree of the preimage of a variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties, arithmetic-degree

Let $V\subset \mathbb{A}^m$ and $W\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ be affine varieties defined over an arbitrary field. Let $f:V\to \mathbb{A}^n$ be a morphism given by polynomials of degree $\leq D$.

Is it true that
$$\deg(f^{-1}(W)) \leq \deg(V) \deg(W) D^{\dim(\overline{f(V)})}?$$

Here, by "degree", we mean "sum of the degrees of the irreducible components".

---

Here is what I have:

- a proof of the above when $\dim(W) = 0$ (call this Lemma 1),
- a proof of the simple bound $\deg(\overline{f(V)})\leq \deg(V) D^{\dim(\overline{f(V)})}$ (call this Lemma 2),
- a proof of the weaker bound $\leq \deg(V) \deg(W) D^{\dim V}$ (UPDATE - I do use this (call it Lemma 3), and prove it, in my self-answer. The proof uses Lemma 2.)

---

Is there a short, clean actual proof? UPDATE: I claim there is one, and in fact I can prove a stronger, tight bound; see self-answer. I use Lemma 2 and 3 above, but not Lemma 1. Lemma 2 was pointed out to me here ([Degree of image of a polynomial map](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63451/degree-of-image-of-a-polynomial-map)) a long time ago.

PS. Talk of "wonky steps" in the comments refers to a previous attempt at a proof by me (with steps clearly marked as "wonky" by me). The current proof would seem to be correct.

PPS (added a few weeks later). I was recently talking to two algebraic geometers while on semi-vacation. I realize now that there's a potential ambiguity that may make the lack of additional technical conditions in the above rub people the wrong way. When I write $f^{-1}(W)$, I mean the set-theoretic ("geometric"?) preimage, that is, the variety consisting of the points $x$ such that $f(x)$ lies in $W$. It is not the same as the scheme-theoretic or ideal-theoretic preimage, for which the statement would not be true in general without added conditions.

Indeed, Fulton-Macpherson's generalized Bézout theorem (which is the howitzer in the proof) would not be true without extra conditions if the intersection of two varieties $V$ and $W$ were interpreted in the ideal-theoretic sense.

Fortunately the set-theoretic ("geometric"?) preimage (that is, the  reduced subscheme of the scheme-theoretic preimage) is what I actually need.

I feel a tad wiser now, and would like to explain the above, but I'm not sure of the format to use; it is not a question. Should I give another self-answer (crediting the two algebraic geometers)?

Comment: Is that possible that there is a typo and that you want $D^{dim f^{-1}(W)}$ instead of $D^{dim \overline{f(V)}}$? Also, do you assume that $W$ is in the open locus in the base where $f$ is flat?

Comment: 1.No, I actually want $D^{\dim \overline{f(V})}$. 2. You mean the open locus where f^{-1}(f(x)) is always of the right dimension? No.

Comment: Why? Is there a counterexample?

Comment: I don't have a counter-example yet. Do we assume $W$ is a complete intersection, or something? I guess that the proof of your "Lemma1" rely on the fact that any point in $\mathbb{A}^n$ is a complete intersection of $n$ hyperplanes.

Comment: Don't assume anything about $W$! I mean, of course you can assume that $V$ and $W$ are both irreducible.

Comment: I think that your "wonky step 1" is indeed wonky, by "souping up" the failure in the dimension 0 case.  For your $V$, we can take a blowup of the plane at a point, and for your map we can take the contraction.  Embed $V$ into affine space so that the exceptional divisor becomes a curve of degree at least $2$.  For a $W$, we take a line that passes through the origin, so that $f^{-1}(W)$ is a union of two curves, one mapping isomorphically onto its image, and one which is contracted.  When we take a hyperplane section of $f^{-1}(W)$, it will have to have many points of the contracted curve.

Comment: Right, this shows that the wonkiness of step 1 can't be cured by applying Lemma 1. I can't see right away whether this gets us closer to a counterexample or a proof!

Comment: @Libli The proof of Lemma 1 is simple: a) reduce to the case $\dim \overline{f(V)} = n$ by a projection $\pi:\mathbb{A}^n\to \mathbb{A}^{\dim \overline{f(V)}}$ such that $\pi^{-1}(\pi(y))\cap \overline{f(V)}$ is $0$-dimensional; b) that case is easy, by Bézout. I suppose b) does, in a soft sense, use the fact that a point is a complete intersection, but it is not clear to me that that assumption is needed.

I thought generalizing (a) might be tricky, but now it seems to me we only need that $\pi^{-1}(\pi(y))\cap \overline{f(V)}$ be $\dim(W)$-dimensional. There should be such a $\pi$, no?

Comment: @Libl Assuming there is such a $\pi$, we have a reduction of the problem to the case $V = \mathbb{A}^m$ (since we can just extend the domain of the morphism to $\mathbb{A}^m$ and use Bézout in the last step).

Comment: Wait, maybe this is an easy problem? Intersect $f^{-1}(W)$ with a linear variety of complementary dimension, and restrict $f$ to the intersection of $V$ with that linear variety. We have thus reduced matters to the case of $f^{-1}(W)$ zero-dimensional. If the above argument works, we can also assume that $\dim \overline{f(V)} = n$. We can avoid the silliness with closure by working projectively, i.e., we just work with $f$ mapping surjectively to $\mathbb{P}^n$. But then $f^{-1}(W)$ zero-dimensional implies $W$ zero-dimensional, and we've reduced matters to Lemma 1.

Comment: In fact, we don't even need "if the above argument works". Since $f(f^{-1}(W))$ is $0$-dimensional, we can just choose a $\pi$ such that $\pi^{-1}(\pi(y))$ is $0$-dimensional for every point $y$ on $f(f^{-1}(W))$. That is enough to reduce to the case of $\dim \overline{f(V)} = n$. Is this really that easy? Or is there wonkiness anywhere?

Comment: @HAHelfgott : when you intersect $f^{-1}(W)$ with a linear space $L$, you loose all control on the degree of $f(f^{-1}(W) \cap L)$ (take for instance the degree of the image of a hyperplane by the Veronese embedding).

Comment: You might be interested in looking at a book like Fulton's one (on intersection theory). Some rigour has been put into that subject, precisely to avoid the kind of "wonky" arguments (as you called them) that were the pregorative of the Italian School in its degenerating era.

Comment: The moral of Fulton's book is that if you don't make any asumption on $f$ (like flat or lci or more generally finite-tor dimension) or on $W$ (like complete intersection), it is unlikely you get something interesting. It would very helpful for people trying to answer your question that you give more details on how $V$, $f$ and $W$ arise in your setting.

Comment: @Libli Well, I do seem to have a sketch of a working proof now; see the above! Do your worst to break it.

Comment: (I don't think I'm making any assumptions on the degree of $f(f^{-1}(L))$.)

Comment: My one concern is that I have been imprecise by taking projections after projectivising, but I *think* that's harmless here.

Comment: @Libli What the degree of Veronese varieties shows is that what I called "Lemma 2" is tight, no?

Comment: Let me remove my first attempt at a possible proof from the question and keep its first couple of steps here, so that others' comments will make sense. The degree of $f^{-1}(W)$ is just the number of points of intersection of $f^{-1}(W)$ with a generic linear variety $L$ of codimension $d = \dim(f^{-1}(W))$. "Generically" (wonky step 1) we can expect that no two of those finitely many points get mapped to the same point on $W$. [This step really was wonky; I pointed out it was quite false when $\dim W\cap \overline{f(V)} = 0$, and @JackHuizenga helpfully "souped up" this example.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I'm editing my original answer slightly so as to work in affine space, for the sake of clarity, since, in the proof of Lemma 3 in the comments, I am really working in affine space. If one needs degree bounds of the kind I'm giving in projective space (not that I do), one can just deduce them from the bounds in affine space, by choosing a copy of $\mathbb{A}^n$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ such that the complement of $\mathbb{A}^n$ does not contain any of the varieties we are working with. Of course one can do exactly that to prove a projective version of Lemma 3 using the affine version whose proof is in the comments.]

Let $L\subset \mathbb{A}^m$ be a hyperplane of codimension $\dim f^{-1}(W)$ intersecting $f^{-1}(W)$ at $\deg f^{-1}(W)$ points. We restrict to $L$, and have thus reduced matters to the case where $f^{-1}(W)$ is zero-dimensional. (We have exchanged $V$ for $V\cap L$, which of course has degree $\leq \deg(V)$; we haven't touched $W$.)

We can assume now that $V$ (our new $V$) is irreducible, without loss of generality. Then Theorem 2 in section 1.8 of Mumford's Red Book shows that, because $f^{-1}(W)$ is zero-dimensional, we must have $\dim \overline{f(V)} = \dim V$. But then we have our result by Lemma 3 above:
$$\deg(f^{-1}(W)) \leq \deg(V) \deg(W) D^{\dim V} = \deg(V) \deg(W) D^{\dim \overline{f(V)}}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\textrm{QED}.$$

---

In fact, since we can take $L$ to be generic, we can assume that $V\cap L$ (our new $V$) has dimension $\dim V - \textrm{codim}(L) = \dim V - \dim f^{-1}(W)$. By the same result in Mumford, $\dim f^{-1}(W) \geq \dim(\overline{f(V)\cap W}) + \dim V - \dim \overline{f(V)}$, and so we have really proved that
$$\deg(f^{-1}(W)) \leq \deg(V) \deg(W) D^{\dim V - \dim f^{-1}(V)} = \deg(V) \deg(W) D^{\dim(\overline{f(V)}) - \dim(\overline{f(V)\cap W})}.$$
(EDIT: I earlier wrote $\overline{f(V)}\cap W$ here. With the argument as written above, one must work with $\overline{f(V)\cap W}$, as the result in Mumford requires dominance.

It seems to me that one can indeed get $\overline{f(V)}\cap W$ by being a little more roundabout: prove a projective version of Lemma 3 using the affine version of Lemma 3 (choosing a copy $U$ of $\mathbb{A}^n$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ such that $\mathbb{P}^n\setminus U$ does not contain any components of $f^{-1}(W)$, where $W$ is a projective variety)
and then work projectively. This is a bit of a detour.)

At least if $\overline{f(V)} = \mathbb{A}^n$, this new bound is tight in general: if $W$ is given as a complete intersection of hypersurfaces $g_i(\vec{y})=0$, $1\leq i\leq r$ of degree $D_i$ with $\prod_i D_i = \deg(W)$, then $f^{-1}(W)$ is the intersection of $V$ with the hypersurfaces $(g_i\circ f)(\vec{x})=0$ of degree $D_i D$, and so the degree of $f^{-1}(W)$ should be
$$\deg(V) \prod_{i=1}^r D_i D = \deg(V) \prod_{i=1}^r D_i \cdot D^{\textrm{codim}(W)} =  \deg(V) \deg(W)D^{\dim(\overline{f(V)}) - \dim(\overline{f(V)}\cap W)}.$$

Comment: Here is a proof of Lemma 3 (namely, $\deg(f^{-1}(W)) \leq \deg(V) \deg(W) D^{\dim V}$). Let $g:V\to V\times \mathbb{A}^n$ be given
by $g(x) = (x,f(x))$ and let $\pi_1$ be the projection 
$V\times \mathbb{A}^n \to V$.
Then
$$f^{-1}(W) = \pi_1(g(V)\cap (\mathbb{A}^m\times W)),$$ and so, by Bézout and Lemma 2,
$$\begin{aligned}\deg(f^{-1}(W)) \leq \deg(g(V) \cap (\mathbb{A}^m\times W))\leq
\deg(g(V)) \deg(W) \leq \deg(V) \deg(W) D^{\dim(V)}.
\end{aligned}$$
(Whether this was my own past self, my coauthor Daniele Dona or someone on MathOverflow, I cannot recall.)

Comment: I think Lemma 3 came out implicitly from my side, given the amount of time I was thinking about both Lemma 2 and this projection trick, but I'm not advancing a claim. Lemma 2 came from [this much older question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63451/degree-of-image-of-a-polynomial-map).

Comment: @D.Dona I'm very happy to credit it to you, and at any rate it's all going to come out on work by both of us!

Comment: I'm also wondering how come this all (my self-answer included) isn't at least as old as Fulton or Chevalley or the Sumerians or what have you.

Comment: @libli It has been a couple of days, so I hope the above allays your concerns.

Comment: Your "proof" of Lemma3 seems to be wonky-wonky. Assume $g(V)$ is a line in $\mathbb{P}^3$, $W= \mathbb{P}^1$ and $m=1$. Then the intersection of $W \times \mathbb{A}^1$ with $g(V)$ consists of $2$ points, and so has degree $2$. While $\deg(W) \deg(g(V)) =1$.

Comment: So lemma 3 is not proven and hence your "pseudo-proof" of your claimed result is not correct. The reason this proof does not appear in any Sumerians textbooks is because it's just plain wrong, and not at even at the level of the Sumerians. Perhaps you could be slightly more modest and not dare to put yourself at the same level as Chevalley and Fulton?

Comment: @Libli I'm afraid I can't quite understand your example. Are you claiming you have two linear varities in $\mathbb{P}^3$ that intersect in two points? If that's not what you claim, I don't see how it affects what I've said; all I've used in that step is Bézout's theorem in its general form (as in Fulton) - and in affine space at that.

Comment: @Libli Obviously what I meant by my remark is that this feels like very classical.stuff and I would think it has to be in the literature (assuming it is correct, obviously); I can't see how anybody could have honestly interpreted my remark as you claim to have. But let us focus on the math.

Comment: Just to be clear: everything in the proof of Lemma 3 is to be understood in affine space. What is the questionable step then?

Comment: (I suspect you are tacitly using a Segre embedding, which of course is not of degree 1. As I said, let us work entirely in affine space, at least in the proof of Lemma 3.)

Comment: I don't want to turn this into the parrot sketch, but I'd say Lemma 3 is completely correct (and so is its proof).

Comment: ... and that so are the statement in my answer and the proof in my answer (but everybody is obviously welcome to still tell me if there's something unclear or there is a mistake). I take a partial answer to the Sumerian meta-question is that, before Fulton and Macpherson came up with intersection theory (which is what is really under the hood of what I've called "Bézout" in the above - really generalized Bézout), giving a general result like this, valid for all varieties, would have been hard.

Comment: Update: I was just talking to an algebraic geometer last week - it all checks out. He said a more grown-up proof might go through the Chow variety.

Comment: Confusingly, generalized Bézout is stated only for hypersurfaces on the Wikipedia page on Bézout's theorem. There's a lot going on under the hood in Fulton's book!